# Does the Linux scheduler need to execute on every core in a multicore?

Tags: linux-kernel, multiprocessing, operating-system, multicore

Is it possible for a kernel scheduler thread executing on one core to handle the scheduling of threads/processes for a different remote core, or is it necessary for every core to have their own kernel scheduler thread to handle which thread/process execute on it at any given time? For reference, I am curious about how this would work for an OS implementation similar to [1], which proposes using some cores in a multicore for applications and others for kernel tasks.

[1] Q. Yuan, J. Zhao, M. Chen and N. Sun, "GenerOS: An asymmetric operating system kernel for multi-core systems," 2010 IEEE International Symposium on Parallel & Distributed Processing (IPDPS), 2010, pp. 1-10, doi: 10.1109/IPDPS.2010.5470363.

Comment: If you're talking specifically about Linux, yes the scheduler needs to run on each core. However there's nothing stopping you from creating an OS where scheduler code runs on a core different than the one it is scheduling tasks for.

Comment: In such a theoretical OS where scheduler code runs on a core different than the one it is scheduling tasks for, how would the swapping of applications on the cores which the scheduler is not executing on work? For example, how would preemption be implemented to stop the currently executing application and swap it out?

Comment: There really isn't an answer. It's more or less up to the fantasy of the OS developer in terms of implementation.

Comment: I queue up a preemption request in shared memory and explicitly hardware-interrupt the target core, so forcing it into the OS so it can handle such queued requests.